# Can't launch iOS app developed with Delphi XE8

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have created a Multi-device application with Delphi XE8 with only a button and a label that I deploy to my iPhone. I have set up all the provisioning correctly so it deploys and installs just fine but when I try to launch it the app crashes immediately. I have SDK 8.4, the Mac is OS X 10.10 and the iPhone is 8.4.1.

I looked at the following [link](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/answers/ios-app-won-t-launch) and removed all the line feeds as suggested but that didn't help.

Does anyone have similar problems or a possible solution to why the app won't start?

Comment: You should give us more information . Have you any log entries to show ?

Comment: @aleroot Don't really know what else to give... I can't debug in the IDE since the app crashes immediately. In XCode I think one of the logs from the phone is my test app crashing but it says unknown so I don't know.

Comment: Do you have Delphi XE8 with update 1?

Comment: No, just XE8 without the update

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547414/projects-fail-to-start-in-ios-when-adding-xsuperobject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install XE8 update 1. This fixes an issue that an application won't start on iOS if it uses pcrelib. My guess is that you're using that directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with XE8, 8.3 SDK, XCode8 on a iPad running iOS9.3

The issue was carriage return line feeds in my EntitlementIOS.xml file located in my project.

In NotePad++ you can show carriage return line feeds' symbol (CR LF) in View->Show Symbol->Show all characters

Quick fix : remove carriage line return line feeds

source : https://community.embarcadero.com/answers/ios-app-won-t-launch